Can you link each module in an IntelliJ project to its own remote Git repository?
We used to have a repository on SVN that hosted all our apps. I used git svn to communicate with that repository. In my root directory, I have individual modules, corresponding to individual apps, and a .git folder with a config file that contains this:
[svn-remote "svn"]  
 url = <the repo's url>
 fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn 

Now, we have, thankfully, transitioned to Git. The problematic part is that every app is now a separate Git repository. It means I can't just add a new remote and fetch from there. Instead, I should either (re)create each app as a new project or somehow add matching Git repositories to each of the modules in my IntelliJ project
I read these three SO questions (1, 2, 3), but they don't appear to answer my question
It's true, I can map individual directories to VCSes in Settings -> Version Control -> Directory Mappings. However, I can't map individual directories (or better still, modules) to particular Git repositories. If I then add a Git remote, it seems to be added to the project as a whole rather than a particular module. After I removed those three lines from the config file, added a Git repo for one of the modules that I mapped to Git in the settings, pressed Fetch, nothing happened. Here's what my config looked like afterwards
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true

[submodule]
    active = .

[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master

[remote "origin"]
    url = <url of one of the apps' Git repository>
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

module root mapped to Git
Here's another thing that I tried

Removed the .git folder from the project root altogether
Initialized a Git repository in one of the module's root
Manually added an origin remote pointing to a corresponding Git repository
Fetched changes

(steps from 2 to 4 were performed in the console)
It seemed to go successfully. However, my IntelliJ GUI doesn't show any branching, only the console tab
no branching tab in the Git view in IntelliJ
How can you link each module in an IntelliJ project to its own remote Git repository?
